# Alternative way to access and retrieve data from an Excel file on the cloud

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive, power-automate

Here is the situation: I have an Excel file with macros and VBA programming that makes some data ETL-like job with the data of other Excel file. For testing purpose, the data source file I was working with was a simulated one in local, and, as always, it works.

The problem: the real data source file is one generated by Azure Power Automate and saved in a folder in the cloud. The file with macros is in local for each user. As the data source is on the cloud, we tried next options.

1. FollowHiperlink: only opens the file in the browser, but I cannot reference it as a workbook.
2. Make a task for each time that Azure creates the source file, should be copied in another folder to sync up with the OneDrive folder on user's Macs. So, for me, it should be work like a local file. Searching, I found some solutions for get the path to local OneDrive. But seems that sync up from Azure is getting problems since is always asking for a PIN or password to move the file.
3. If I upload the file with macros to OneDrive's cloud, assuming that there is not access problems due to permissions, the VBA programming will work? Until now I only worked in local or against at database.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: What if you just open the file directly using `Workbooks.Open(urlHere)` ?

Comment: You could do as Tim says which is probably what I would do, or sync the SharePoint folder to your file explorer and then be able to reference it with a file path.

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried it but gave an error like "not recognized". I don't remember well because it was in another language that is not mother language or English. I will try again today to be sure.

Comment: @data_sc That was our idea because it should be an automate task, but when we see it wasn't syncing, the person in charge noticed that cloud was sending a confirmation PIN. He was working on it on Friday so maybe we are lucky and works smooth today.